# how to pass a static char array to another class safely

Tags: c++

I was wondering if someone could help me understand how to securely pass a static unsigned char array from one class to another. My apologies if this is trivial but I wanted to be sure I do it right.

for example

```
// First Class
unsigned char data[1024];

TMainClass::TMainClass()
{
    data[34] = 1;
    data[45] = 65;
    ...
    TOtherClass obj(data);
};



// Second class
static unsigned char obtainedData[1024];

TOtherClass::TOtherClass(unsigned char* _data)
{
    obtainedData = _data;

};
```

Comment: Define "safely" and "securely".

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using an stl or boost container. If, however, you have a good reason not to, then ...

You're passing it just fine, but the assignment is wrong.

```
obtainedData = _data;
```

You should really either copy the data

```
memcpy(obtainedData, _data, 1024);
std::copy(_data, _data+1024, obtainedData) // Thanks @Grizzly
```

or redefine the obtainedData variable

```
static unsigned char* obtainedData;
```

Notes:

Be sure you think about the size of the arrays you're passing and copying to. Are they guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: Thanks man, that's awesome, ill give that a go :) and yes they are gonna be the same size

Comment: @Grizzly nice! Unfortunately, when I see a C-style array and need to copy it, I immediately think memcpy. I gotta break that ...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "securely" or "safely"?

Your types are wrong ( you don't assign 1 array to another like that).

And this is c++  so really what you should probably be doing is using a std::string or std::vector or even if you need a fixed buffer std::array